# Physical meaning of the terms in the Mattis-Bardeen Integrals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, superconductivity

**Mattis-Bardeen Integrals**

The Mattis-Bardeen integrals for the complex conductivity $\sigma = \sigma_1-j\sigma_2$ of a superconductor describe the electromagnetic response to a high frequency drive.

There are three integrals, two for the real (dissipative) part, $\sigma_1$, and one for the imaginary (inductive) part, $\sigma_2$:

$$\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_n}=\frac{2}{\hbar\omega}\int_\Delta^\infty[f(E)-f(E+\hbar\omega)]N(E)N(E+\hbar\omega)F(\Delta,E,E+\hbar\omega)dE\\+\frac{1}{\hbar\omega}\int_{\text{min}(\Delta-\hbar\omega,-\Delta)}^{-\Delta}[1-2f(E+\hbar\omega)]N(E)N(E+\hbar\omega)F(\Delta,E,E+\hbar\omega)dE$$

and

$$\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_n}=\frac{-j}{\hbar\omega}\int_{\text{max}(\Delta-\hbar\omega)}^{\Delta}[1-2f(E+\hbar\omega)]N(E)N(E+\hbar\omega)F(\Delta,E,E+\hbar\omega)dE$$

where $\sigma_n$ is the conductivity in the normal state, $\omega$ is the drive frequency, $\Delta$ is the superconducting gap, $f$ is the Fermi function, $N(E)$ is the density of states for quasiparticles, and $F$ contains the type II BCS coherence factors.

**Physical interpretation of the first integral**

The first integral is easy to interpret.  It describes the response of thermally excited quasiparticles to the drive.  The rate of excitation from $E$ to $E+\hbar\omega$ will be proportional to
$$N(E)f(E) \times N(E+\hbar\omega)[1-f(E+\hbar\omega)]$$
Likewise, the rate of decay from $E+\hbar\omega$ to $E$ will be proportional to:
$$N(E+\hbar\omega)f(E+\hbar\omega) \times N(E)[1-f(E)]$$
Subtracting these terms gives the net transition rate, proportional to
$$[f(E)-f(E+\hbar\omega)]N(E)N(E+\hbar\omega)$$
as seen in the first integral.

(I am not worrying about the BCS coherence factors here or anywhere else going forward).

**Physical interpretation of the second integral**

The meaning of the second integral is also clear (mostly from the bounds), but I am having trouble tracking down the parts in the same way that I did for the first integral.  Likewise, I cannot find a simple breakdown of the terms anywhere in the literature.

This integral describes pair-breaking, and only appears for $\hbar\omega > 2\Delta$, as can be seen by the bounds.  However, none of the other factors make sense to me.  For instance, why does the density of states enter in at both $E$ *and* $E+\hbar\omega$ when the Fermi function only enters in at $E+\hbar\omega$?  And where does the $1-2f(E+\hbar\omega)$ term come from?

**Physical interpretation of the third integral (the imaginary term)**

The third integral is where I really run into trouble. This term describes the inductive response to the ac drive of the Cooper pairs and of the quasiparticles.

At zero temperature, this reduces to $\pi\Delta/\hbar\omega$, which makes sense to me, because it is the same result you get for a Josephson inductance using the Ambegoakar-Baratoff expression (and loosely speaking, we can look at a superconducting wire as a long chain of tunnel junctions).

But again, where does the $1-2f(E+\hbar\omega)$ term come from and why do we still have the density of states at both $E$ and $E+\hbar\omega$?  Also, how were we allowed to multiply by $-j$ to make the density of states, which otherwise would have been undefined due to a factor of $1/\sqrt{E^2-\Delta^2}$?

(I recognize that normally this integral is not given in terms of the densities of states, but there *has* to be an underlying physical reason that the expressions can be written in this way...)

**Summary and Re-statement of question**

There are three integrals given by Mattis-Bardeen theory to describe the ac response of a superconductor.

The first integral describes the net transition rate of thermally excited quasiparticles to higher energies by the drive, and the origin of all of the terms are clear.

The second integral describes loss due to pair breaking, and with the way that the integral can be written $[1-2f(E+\hbar\omega)]N(E)N(E+\hbar\omega)$, it seems clear that there should be a simple physical explanation for each of those terms.

Finally, the third integral describes the inductive response (dominated by Cooper pairs, but including both Cooper pairs and quasiparticles).  This integral looks qualitatively like the second integral but describes the frequency regime more akin to the first integral.

*What is the simple physical explanation for each of the terms in the second and third Mattis-Bardeen integrals?*